# Call sub not working but code works when placed in sub that is doing the calling

Tags: vba, excel

Should be a quick and easy one for you folks, why does this not work?

Code restricts user to enter only text in a textbox. 
It works fine, but I have about 50 textbox's so would be cleaner and easier to Call instead.

However, done like this the restriction no longer works

```
Private Sub OnlyAcceptText()
 'Forces the textbox to only accept text
  If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122)Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

Code in textbox by KeyPress:

```
Private Sub AgencyContactTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
'Calls sub that only allows text in texctbox
  Call OnlyAcceptText
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to pass the keyascii argument to.  OnlyAcceptText(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Nathan_Sav comment, you can also add a second parameter to your `OnlyAcceptText` Sub, that identifes the Caller `TextBox`.

```
Private Sub AgencyContactTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

' use can also add the TB as indentifier
OnlyAcceptText AgencyContactTextBox, KeyAscii

End Sub

'========================================================================

Private Sub OnlyAcceptText(ByRef TB As MSForms.TextBox, ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    With TB
        If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For 50 text boxes though, I would investigate event sinking a textbox, and doing that way, within the class.  A little slicker, and a few lines of code opposed to 50x lines.  Glad you've sorted though.

Answer (score 3):

Using event sinking, youd have a class, with an event sunk text box inside, something like so

```
Private WithEvents t As MSForms.TextBox

Public Sub INITIALISE(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set t = tb
End Sub

Private Sub t_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii =0
End Sub
```

Then you'd need to make a collection, to hold the 50 classes, which would mimic `me.controls` as a collection, but just for the custom text boxes.

```
Public colCustomTextboxes As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
        set t=new clsCustomTextBox
        t.INITIALISE c
        colCustomTextboxes.Add t
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: You must have read my mind, that was my next question! - "Is there a way to do this for all the textboxes I need it to" - Rather than 4 lines of code for each textbox (200 in total!). I will give this a try.