# Same code for multi textboxes Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

There are about 100 textboxes in my Userform, and I hope to make 10 of those textboxes to call sub after event change, and I have tried to avoid to make a code for each of the boxes like:

```
Private Sub ItemInput1_1_Change()
OriItemCode = ItemInput1_1.Value
Call IndexMatchItem
ItemInput1_5.Value = MatchItemCodeOutput
End Sub

Private Sub ItemInput2_1_Change()
OriItemCode = ItemInput2_1.Value
Call IndexMatchItem
ItemInput2_5.Value = MatchItemCodeOutput
End Sub

Private Sub ItemInput3_1_Change()
OriItemCode = ItemInput3_1.Value
Call IndexMatchItem
ItemInput3_5.Value = MatchItemCodeOutput
End Sub
```

so I ended up have a silly thought and come up with the few lines of code below for the specific boxes event change, but it doesnt work.

I did some research on that but unfortunately, those tutorial are only for all textboxes which I couldnt applied them in my excel.

It would be much appropriated if any VBA pros can give me a hand to change the codes below to make it works, so that I dont have to create event change for each textbox.

Thanks

```
Private Sub Box2Box3Box4Changeevent()

Dim i
Dim j

For i = 1 To 10

If Me.Controls("ItemInput" & i & "_" & 1 & "_" & "Afterupdate") Then
Call Box2ChangeBox4
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760029/call-sub-not-working-but-code-works-when-placed-in-sub-that-is-doing-the-calling/42762561#42762561

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this solution for all textboxes in my userform or I can modify it for the specific boxes I want?

Comment: You can do what ever you want, set the names to be something like stdTbx# and custTbx#, then check the start of the names and only do it to text boxes on the form where the `.name` starts with custTbx say.

Comment: Thanks for that,

Comment: I have used Left( .name, 9) = "Iteminput" to make it happened :)

Comment: Good.  Did you put this in the add to the collection part, or within the class?  It will work in either, but in the class you could make certain events happen based on it's name, if you just want standard or one function handled like this, then just do it at the collection adding part.

Comment: Yes, I am working on that.

Comment: Thanks for making my day easy :)

Comment: Btw I have another Problem, that I want to loop the textbox like : For i = 1 To 4

frmDataEntry.Control("TextBox" & i).Value = frmDataEntry.Control("Box" & i).Value

Next i, but it doesnt work @Nathan_Sav

Comment: loop when event change

Comment: `controls`  its a collection of `control`'s in the class you'll need to pass in the form as with the textbox, so `INIT(tb as textbox,frm as userform)`

Comment: thinking on it, you can get the form from the control I believe to.

Comment: Done , thanks a lot :)

Comment: Good man.  Use this as a spring board to the world of classes, will reduce coding a lot also.